# Get Specific Column Names in SYNONYM in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, synonym

With this query I can successfully get a list of  column names for an Oracle table.

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'TBL_NEWS' 
AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE ('GLOBE_%') 
ORDER BY  COLUMN_ID
```

I have a synonym and I need to get all column names of that synonym also. So how can I extend above query to get all column names in Synonym starting `GLOBE_` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A synonym does not have columns, the table it refers to has. So you might use this:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS atc
JOIN ALL_SYNONYMS als ON atc.table_name = als.table_name
WHERE als.SYNONYM_NAME='my_synonym'
  AND als.OWNER IN (USER, 'PUBLIC')
  AND atc.COLUMN_NAME LIKE ('GLOBE_%')
ORDER BY atc.COLUMN_ID
```

Comment: Synonym can be for a view as well from other schema, above answer excludes the views, but just considers the tables. Isn't it ?

Comment: @SrikanthA: Actually, it works for views as well, since `USER_TAB_COLUMNS` also contains views' columns.

Comment: Right, and the other schemas - How about using a ALL_TAB_COLUMNS

Comment: @SrikanthA: OK, Changed that to ALL_TAB_COLUMNS.

Comment: remove `AND als.OWNER IN (USER, 'PUBLIC')` and `AND atc.COLUMN_NAME LIKE ('GLOBE_%')` and see if you get something. Also keep in mind that identifiers in Oracle are usually upper case (unless "quoted") so use upper case for synonym name and column name.

Comment: Unfortunately, in Oracle you can create synonyms for other synonyms, which I don't think this answer will handle.  The column name `ALL_SYNONYMS.TABLE_NAME` is misleading: if the synonym does not point to a table, it does not actually hold a table name.  So, I think a "complete" solution to the OP's question needs to be a little more general.

Comment: ...correct the alias in the first join from utc to atc

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the extent of Schema you want data from - u can use ALL_TAB_COLUMNS and ALL_SYNONYMS OR DBA_TAB_COLUMNS and DBA_SYNONYMS

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS ATC JOIN ALL_SYNONYMS ALS ON ATC.table_name = ALS.table_name WHERE ALS.SYNONYM_NAME='my_synonym'      AND ATC.COLUMN_NAME LIKE ('GLOBE_%') ORDER BY ATC.COLUMN_ID;

or 


SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM DBA_TAB_COLUMNS DTC JOIN DBA_SYNONYMS DS ON DTC.table_name = DS.table_name WHERE DS.SYNONYM_NAME='my_synonym'    AND DTC.COLUMN_NAME LIKE ('GLOBE_%') ORDER BY DTC.COLUMN_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of querying data dictionary. You can create function to return list of column in table/view/synonym.

```
create type list_varchar2 is table of varchar2(100);
/
create or replace function  list_of_column(p_name in varchar2) return list_varchar2 PIPELINED  
    is
        v_Cnt        number :=  0;
        v_table_description       dbms_sql.desc_tab;
        c_curosor     integer default dbms_sql.open_cursor;
   begin
       dbms_sql.parse(  c_curosor, 'select * from '|| p_name||' where 1 = 2', dbms_sql.native );
       dbms_sql.describe_columns( c       => c_curosor,
                                  col_cnt => v_Cnt,
                                  desc_t  => v_table_description );

       for i in 1 .. v_Cnt
       loop

           pipe row ( v_table_description(i).col_name );

        end loop;
       dbms_sql.close_cursor(c_curosor);
   exception
       when others then dbms_sql.close_cursor( c_curosor );
           raise;
   end ;
/
select * from table(list_of_column('table_name'))
/
select * from table(list_of_column('view_name'))
/
select * from table(list_of_column('synonym'))
/
```